# Change the background of date picker dialog programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am showing DatePicker in dialog by following this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker), The dialog is showing white background which does not matches my app branding, so I want to change its color.

How can I do that programmatically ? Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its mostly depends on your `application theme`

> If you use android:Theme.Light for your application theme it looks like the below screenshot

[image]

> if you use android:Theme.Holo for your application theme it looks like the below screenshot

[image]

**EDIT :** use [**HoloEverywhere**](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) project for your application theme.

Comment: I am using this theme `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"` How can I change it to dark ?

Answer (score -1):

Try with `android:background="#000000"` or another hex color

Comment: This is  wrong answer! I am not using xml, rather it is shown programatically in dialog box, cant u see the source code in the link provided